# publish web application ASP.NET MVC (database first)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How to add the EntityFrameWork model to build dll? After the publish application pages that use model does not work.
connection strings:

```
<add name="printerServiceDbConnection" connectionString="workstation id=printerServiceDb.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=dmitry_SQLLogin_1;pwd=1svt28jh1f;data source=printerServiceDb.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=printerServiceDb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="printerServiceDbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EFModel.csdl|res://*/EFModel.ssdl|res://*/EFModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=printerServiceDb.mssql.somee.com;initial catalog=printerServiceDb;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Entity Framework Package via the Package manager console it will automatically reference the dll's

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0
```

[image]

Comment: By hosting EFmodel already exists. No access to the models that were created using EF.

Comment: The models automatically get added in the build once you publish your site

Comment: why do u have two connections?

Comment: I was thinking: one connection string  is needed for connection to db; second - for connection to EF. To local server it works.

Comment: No one is enough for connection if you are using EF then the ef connection string is enough

Comment: If added System.Data.EntityClient (instead System.Data.SqlClient) connection in WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("my_connection", "Users", "UserId", "Email", autoCreateTables: true); throws an exception: "Unable to find the requested data provider. Net Framework. Maybe it is not installed."